# syntax error (Sqlite code 1 SQLITE_ERROR)

Tags: java, database, sqlite, android-studio

i want to query all data from my table where Name_s = value intent

It fails on this line in the class:
`Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);`

My class :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mushroom);

        dbhp = new DatabaseHelper(this);

        NS = getIntent().getStringExtra("name_s");

        txtName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textName);
        txtType = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textType);
        txtName_s = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textName_s);
        txtFeature = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textFeature);
        txtProperties = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textProperties);
        imageV = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageV);

        SQLiteDatabase db = dbhp.getWritableDatabase();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM " + dbhp.TABLE_NAME + " where " + dbhp.KEY_NAME_S + " = " + NS ;
        Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, null);
        m_name = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_NAME));
        m_name_s = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_NAME_S));
        m_type = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_TYPE));
        m_feature = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_FEATURE));
        m_properties = data.getString(data.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_PROPERTIES));
        m_image = data.getBlob(data.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHelper.KEY_IMAGE));



        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(m_image, 0, m_image.length);

        txtName.setText(m_name);
        txtType.setText(m_type);
        txtName_s.setText(m_name_s);
        txtFeature.setText(m_feature);
        txtProperties.setText(m_properties);
        imageV.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use single quotes around the string `NS`, but even if this would remove the error, it would not be the recommended and also safe way to construct your query.
Use `?` placeholders for each of the parameters that you pass in the sql statement and pass the parameters as a string array in the 2nd argument of `rawQuery()`:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + dbhp.TABLE_NAME + " where " + dbhp.KEY_NAME_S + " = ?";
Cursor data = db.rawQuery(query, new String[] {NS});
```

This way the parameters are taken care by `rawQuery()`, you don't have to concatenate single quotes and your code is safe and without the risk of [sql-injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Comment: This is obviously not related to the question you posted.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL when querying a string value you need to surround the string with quotes. So in your case the code should be:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM " + dbhp.TABLE_NAME + " where " + dbhp.KEY_NAME_S + " = '" + NS + "'";
```

But to make life easier for yourself and prevent such query related problems in the future you might want to look into [Room Persistence](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room). A good article to start with is [this article](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room).